# How to give data in Customer model of one app from SignUpForm form model in another app automatically?

Tags: html, css, django

Here, I am trying to automatically give data in Customer model of one app from SignUpForm form model in another app in Django. How can I do it?

`forms.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=['username','first_name','last_name','email']
        labels = {'email':'Email'}
```

`models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: add your codes in the code sample box, and explain more about your goal and your challenge.

Comment: Do you want to create a Customer object using the data from a User object?

Comment: SignupForm in app1and Customer in app2. If I enter email data in SignForm in app1 then, how can I use the same email data in app2.

Answer (score 0):

If Im getting it right you want to add an customer obj from the form if yes the logic is done in views.py and this example will help you

```
def todo_create(request):
    form = todoCreateForm
    context ={
        'form': form
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =todoUpdateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'todoUpdate.html', context)
```

Comment: Customer model is from one app and SignUpForm is in another app.